# mv *.cache.{js,woff} sub_folder - works as shell command but not inside a Makefile

Tags: bash, wildcards, make

After building something with `make` I want to move all the files that end in `.cache.{js,woff}` to a sub folder.

```
(cd $(PFROOT)/PVWR2/gwt/pdfwebviewer/; \
mkdir -p cache_files; \
mv *.cache.{js,woff} sub_folder)
```

The problem is, when running `make` it seems to interpret `*.cache.{js,woff}` as a file name and not something dynamic and of course there is no file that has the explicit name `*.cache.{js,woff}`.
When I just navigate to the folder and move it manually from the shell with above command
it works without a hitch.

I understand it has to do with globbing but I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{...}` is bash-specific syntax for brace expansion, but make uses `/bin/sh` by default instead of `bash`.

From `info make`, section 5.3.2:

> The program used as the shell is taken from the variable `SHELL`. If
>   this variable is not set in your makefile, the program `/bin/sh` is
>   used as the shell.

If you want to use bash to parse shell constructs in your Makefile, you can add the following to the top:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```